# OS X keeps rebooting by itself

Tags: macos

This is a bit weird to start since I work at a AAAC and should at least be able to pinpoint a cause, but:

- I have been having this issue for at least a year
- It spawns three different machines and three OSes (a 13" Mid-2010 MBA, a 13" Mid 2012 MBP and a 13" rMBP Early 2013; Mountain Lion, Mavericks and public betas of Yosemite)
- there are *no* recorded kernel panics for the time it tried to restart itself
- the recorded kernel panics on Console are from sleep/wake issues which have plagued these units (rMBP will be asleep in my bag when I come home, gf will be listening to some tunes on JAMBOX, unit will try to come off sleep and kernel panic. every. damn. time)
- reading the console logs has not taken me very far. I have a couple of weird messages from the last.fm client

  ```
  07/09/14 15:53:50,193 Last.fm Scrobbler[52838]: com.apple.message.domain:            com.apple.automation.osaexecute_run
  com.apple.message.signature: fm.last.Scrobbler
  com.apple.message.signature2: com.apple.applescript
  com.apple.message.summarize: YES
  SenderMachUUID: 4AC11FC1-B379-35FD-B3C9-3CD9798522DE
  ```

  over and over again.
- if I don't keep an app that needs confirmation to quit (iTerm, Transmission, etc), I know I'll come back to find the computer on the login screen.
- it has never happened while I'm using it, only when idle.

Can anyone shed some light on this? What should I be looking for in console logs? I know it must be something in my setup that does this but I can't, for the life of me, figure out what I can be.

EDIT:
I've been getting these messages every 5 seconds for the last few days.

```
10/09/14 22:53:33,659 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.mdworker.bundles[12128]) Could not find uid associated with service: 0: Undefined error: 0 503
10/09/14 22:53:33,662 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.mdworker.bundles) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

Will post a log as soon as it happens again.

EDIT2:
Ok, it happened again last night. I left it at work as we are swamped and I left late and around 2h30 a.m. (i left about an hour earlier) I've got this:

```
11/09/14 02:38:35,710 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.mdworker.bundles[14708]) Could not find uid associated with service: 0: Undefined error: 0 503
11/09/14 02:38:35,717 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.mdworker.bundles) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
11/09/14 02:38:40,000 kernel[0]: PM response took 2922 ms (27, powerd)
11/09/14 02:38:40,000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 480651.089938: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Sleep 
11/09/14 02:38:40,000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 480651.089952: wl0: powerChange: *** BONJOUR/MDNS OFFLOADS ARE NOT RUNNING.
11/09/14 02:38:40,000 kernel[0]: AppleBCM5701Ethernet [en3]: Link down (womp enabled, proxy 478)
11/09/14 02:38:40,000 kernel[0]: AppleBCM5701Ethernet [en3]:        0        0 memWrInd fBJP_Wakeup_Timer
11/09/14 02:38:41,000 kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltNHIType2::waitForOk2Go2Sx - retries = 27
11/09/14 03:38:37,000 kernel[0]: Wake reason: RTC (Alarm)
11/09/14 03:38:37,000 kernel[0]: RTC: SleepService 2014/9/11 02:38:37, sleep 2014/9/11 01:38:42
11/09/14 03:38:37,000 kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltNHIType2::prePCIWake - power up complete - took 1 us
11/09/14 03:38:37,000 kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff804191a600>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 11 unplug = 0
11/09/14 03:38:37,000 kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff804191a600>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 12 unplug = 0
11/09/14 03:38:37,000 kernel[0]: TBT W (2): 0x0100 [x]
11/09/14 03:38:37,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::checkStatus - received Status Packet, Payload 2: device was reinitialized
11/09/14 03:38:37,435 hidd[76]: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
11/09/14 03:38:37,000 kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff804191a600>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 3 unplug = 0
11/09/14 03:38:38,000 kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltGenericHAL::earlyWake - complete - took 1076 milliseconds
11/09/14 03:38:38,000 kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration begin ]
11/09/14 03:38:38,000 kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration end, bridges 13, devices 15 ]
11/09/14 03:38:38,000 kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration begin ]
11/09/14 03:38:38,000 kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration end, bridges 13, devices 15 ]
11/09/14 03:38:38,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en3: interface en is sending notification 0x14
11/09/14 03:38:38,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en3: interface en is going DOWN
11/09/14 03:38:38,000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 480654.086449: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Wake - Full Wake/ Dark Wake / Maintenance wake
11/09/14 03:38:38,000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 480654.086457: AirPort_Brcm43xx::checkInterfacePowerState: Check _pwrOffThreadCall!
11/09/14 03:38:40,571 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.mdworker.bundles[14709]) Could  not find uid associated with service: 0: Undefined error: 0 501
11/09/14 03:38:40,573 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.mdworker.bundles) Service only ran for 1 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 9 seconds.
11/09/14 03:38:40,000 kernel[0]: PM response took 2048 ms (27, powerd)
11/09/14 03:38:40,613 com.apple.backupd-helper[13980]: Attempt to use XPC with a MachService that has HideUntilCheckIn set. This will result in unpredictable behavior: com.apple.backupd.status.xpc
11/09/14 03:38:41,159 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.mdworker.bundles[14710]) Could  not find uid associated with service: 0: Undefined error: 0 503
11/09/14 03:38:41,162 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.mdworker.bundles) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
11/09/14 03:38:42,000 kernel[0]: Ethernet [AppleBCM5701Ethernet]: Link up on en3, 100-Megabit, Full-duplex, Symmetric flow-control, Debug [796d,0301,0de1,0300,4de1,0000]
11/09/14 03:38:42,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en3: interface en is sending notification 0x14
11/09/14 03:38:42,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en3: interface en is coming UP
11/09/14 03:38:42,505 networkd[125]: +[NETLedBelly stopFastFail] Clearing ledbelly failure cache
11/09/14 03:38:42,507 discoveryd[53]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer 192.168.1.254 Port 53 errno 51, fd 71, ErrLogCount 1 ResolverIntf:11
11/09/14 03:38:42,508 configd[26]: network changed: v4(en3-:192.168.1.112) DNS- Proxy-
11/09/14 03:38:42,511 vmnet-bridge[79376]: Dynamic store changed
11/09/14 03:38:42,512 discoveryd[53]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer 192.168.1.254 Port 53 errno 51, fd 71, ErrLogCount 2 ResolverIntf:11
11/09/14 03:38:42,513 discoveryd[53]: Basic Warn DD_Warn: Corrupt NSEC RDATA size
11/09/14 03:38:42,513 vmnet-bridge[79376]: Failed to read SCproperties for key: State:/Network/Global/IPv4
11/09/14 03:38:42,514 vmnet-bridge[79376]: Stopping bridge for: en3
11/09/14 03:38:42,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: VMNetDisconnect called for port 0xffffff805eef1600
11/09/14 03:38:42,000 kernel[0]: en3: promiscuous mode disable succeeded
11/09/14 03:38:42,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en3: disabled promiscuous mode
11/09/14 03:38:42,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en3: filter detached
11/09/14 03:38:42,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en3: down
11/09/14 03:38:42,000 kernel[0]: vmnet: bridge-en3: detached
11/09/14 03:38:42,518 discoveryd[53]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer 192.168.1.254 Port 53 errno 51, fd 71, ErrLogCount 3 ResolverIntf:11
11/09/14 03:38:42,522 discoveryd[53]: Basic WABServer NetResolverEvent no resolvers, resetting domains
```

Hope someone can make better sense of this than I can.
EDIT3:
Jay, you were right, it is in fact logging me out instead of rebooting. Woke up to the login screen this morning, fired up iTerm and...
`norin-raad:~ [user]$ uptime 8:05  up 13 days, 10:41, 2 users, load averages: 10,40 5,00 3,36`

But, I now I feel **really** dumb, after seeing you suggestion I've started googling for my issue plus log out instead of reboot and found the answer: `automatically log off after x minutes of inactivity` was set to 60 minutes. What I find most puzzling other than this being set in the first place is how the hell did this I inherit this setting on a clean install I did of Mavericks. My sincere thanks for your help, guys, I'm going to sit in the corner for a while :)

Comment: Any console records for SMC ? What is the apple script doing ? Feel free to expand your Console record to some 50 lines just in case you missed something, around the time stamp of the event.

Comment: While your post is fine, it does not contain enough information (full console report after wake from sleep) to answer your question.

Comment: Are you sure it's rebooting and not just logging you out? You can run `uptime` in the Terminal to see how long the system has been running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But, I now I feel **really** dumb, after seeing you suggestion I've started googling for my issue plus log out instead of reboot and found the issue: `automatically log off after x minutes of inactivity` was set to 60 minutes. What I find most puzzling other than this being set in the first place is how the hell did this I inherit this setting on a clean install I did of Mavericks. My sincere thanks for your help, guys, I'm going to sit in the corner for a while :)

Comment: While you sit there, do not forget to mark your answer as 'accepted' within a few days. ;)